# I have a syntax error but I dont know why, I think my code is good

Tags: python, function, f-string

I have my function defined:

```
def somme(n1 , n2):
  result = (n1 + n2)
  return (f"The sum of" {n1} "+" {n2} "is equal to" {result})
```

That I call like this:

```
somme(1,1)
```

I get error on `{n1}`:

```
return (f"The sum of" {n1} "+" {n2} "is equal to" {result})
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you get a compiler error then the code is not good.

Comment: indeed, but I dont why I am doing wrong

Comment: You are mixing `fstrings` from python3 and old way of printing from python2. In python2, you would do: `"The sum of " + str(value)` in python3 using fstrings: `f"The sum of {value}"`

Answer (score 0):

f-strings are string literals that have an f at the beginning and curly braces containing expressions that will be replaced with their values. [More information](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)

```
def somme(n1 , n2):
  result = (n1 + n2)
  return (f"The sum of {n1} {n2} is equal to {result}")
```

Comment: thank you for the link, I no understood my error... am a beginner in phyton

Comment: The additional parentheses are not needed

Answer (score 0):

You're constructing your f-string wrongly. Just do this:

```
def somme(n1, n2):
    return f'The sum of {n1} + {n2} is equal to {n1+n2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python a string ends when the closings quotes are found. So when you write:

```
"The sum of" "3 + 4"
```

you are writing two different strings.

Format strings (fstring) substitute every variable between braces inside the string. Your fstring does not even see what happens when the quotes are closed. If you want to have your variable in your string you just write:

```
f"The sum of {n1} + {n2}"
```

Notice that `{n1}` and `{n2}` are both inside your string.

What you wrote is a fstring without any braces, so no substitution is performed. So you have a plain string that closes and just after that a variable between braces (that would be a set). A string, space, a set: that means nothing in Python. Notice that the error is not pointing to your variable: it is pointing the first place the interpreter realizes that your code is not valid.

Your particular case will be like this:

```
f"The sum of {n1} + {n2} is equal to {result}"
```